Excel: disable prompt to save changes on close
I have an excel workbook with macros. I am using a "welcome" sheet to ensure the user enables macros according to the technique illustrated here (http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=379). Everything works fine until I extend the workbook with Power Query. I created a query to read and transform an Excel table located in the same workbook. The transformed table is then loaded in a new sheet in the same workbook. Now I need to refresh this transformed table with VBA whenever the user saves the workbook. I am using this code for the refresh:
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").ListObjects("MyTable").QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

Unfortunately, if the user saves the workbook and closes the workbook immediatly after the saving, a prompt appears to save the changes, even if no changes have been made. For some reason, the refresh of the QueryTable sets ThisWorkbook.Save property to False, and therefore Excel prompts to save the unsaved changes on close.
How can I get rid of the prompt on close if no changes have been made?
Thank you.

Edit:
This is the code of the BeforeSave Event:
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

'Query
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").ListObjects("MyTable").QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

'Turn off events to prevent unwanted loops
Application.EnableEvents = False

'Call customized save routine and set workbook's saved property to true
'(To cancel regular saving)
 Call CustomSave(SaveAsUI)
Cancel = True

'Turn events back on an set saved property to true
Application.EnableEvents = True
ThisWorkbook.Saved = True

End Sub

I don't know where to place the Refresh. I tried to place it alternatively in the Workbook.BeforeSave and Workbook.AfterSave. Nothing works.

In the BeforeClose event, you can save one additional time (just in case the user did not save on their own) and then close with the SaveChanges as False:
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    ThisWorkbook.Save
    ThisWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
End Sub

If your line is in the BeforeSave event, that should be fine still.
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").ListObjects("MyTable").QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End Sub

EDIT
If you don't want the save the user's changes without them hitting the save button use:
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Me.Close SaveChanges:=False
End Sub

If you want to save changes the user makes then use:
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    If Me.Saved = True Then
        ThisWorkbook.Save
    End If
    ThisWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
End Sub

in tandem with:
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    ThisWorkbook.Saved = True
End Sub

In the sheets you want to keep track of. That should cover all the changes made.

Unfortunately, in the BeforeClose event, I can't save one additional time (in case the user did not save on his own) because that would update the last modified date of the file. Last modified date should be updated only if changes were made. I tried to place the Refresh in the BeforeSave event as you suggest, but Excel still prompts me to save changes on close

Where's your check if the query changed and does that have something to do with the mentioned Cancel = True from the other comment on Black Cat's answer? Please update your question with the full (relevant) code to show how you have it now.

I do not check if the query changes. I just refresh the query anyway in the BeforeSave event. The query is refreshed everytime the user saves the workbook. I have just updated my question.

CustomSave from your link still saves the workbook though. Last modified date should be updated only if changes were made but if the user saves, then the modified date automatically gets changed thus my solution should still be able to pass?

'CustomSave' saves the workbook whenever the user clicks the save button. I'm sorry but your solution does not satisfy my needs. Excel should update last modified date only if real changes have been made. The code in your BeforeClose event saves the workbook in any case even if the user just opened the workbook and did nothing. If the user opens the workbook and closes it immediately, the workbook should not be saved and last modified date should not be updated

Edited my answer, let me know if it still doesn't work the way you had in mind.

Pls. try this:
Place your code in the Workbook_BeforeSave() Sub and add this to the module:
Private Sub Workbook_AfterSave(ByVal Success As Boolean)
If Success Then
Me.Saved = True
End If
End Sub

If the save was successful then it set the Saved property of the workbook as it was not modified after the last save.

I hate to say it but Excel still prompts me to save changes on close

This in my (old) version works. Maybe this is version dependent. I cannot reproduce the issue. Sorry.

What do you mean by old version? I am using Excel 2016. Anyway, I added a msgbox before 'Me.saved = True' and it does not apper on screen. So the AfterSave event is not successful

My 2010. (and dont want to change it). place the msgbox out of the if to check that the proc. is executed.

I placed the msgbox outside of the if statement. The proc. is executed correctly

Are you sure that the refresh is executed at all? If there is a problem this can be the reason. Try to comment out that line and check the Close.

AfterSave event is not successful in any case because there is the statement "Cancel = True" in the BeforeSave Event. I know that the refresh is executed because I can see the updated data in the transformed table. In the AfterSave event the statement "Me.Saved = True" does not fix the problem even if it is placed outside of the if statement. Excel still prompts me to save changes on close. Anyway thank you a lot for all the time you gave to me!
